# How to set playback quality in youtube player api

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm using Youtube Player API for playing Youtube videos in my app. The problem I'm facing is that the video when starts playing the quality of video is too low even if the device connected to the wifi. Is there any way to force Youtube Player to play high quality videos in my app using Youtube Player API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no method in the Android YouTube API to achieve this.

So the workaround is to use an IFrame associated with an Android WebView and then, control the video quality.

There is a function in the Youtube IFrame API See: Playback Quality in IFrame Player